# How do I set the correlation id of an operation in app insights js?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a back end system where events are tracked and correlated using app insights. This works great and mostly out of the box by installing the appropriate NuGet packages.

I would now like to add a front end component, while still maintaining request tracking with correlation across the entire application.

The back end system pushes information over sockets to the front end, where I have app insights js installed and configured.
When a new message is received, I would like the front end to call `trackEvent` and for me to be able to see this event as part of the complete operation tracking, starting from the back end, and ending in the front end.

My guess is that I would need to send some correlation value (such as request id) explicitly as part of the socket payload, and then pass the value through to the `trackEvent` call, although I'm not sure which values is needed, nor how would I amend the front end call to ensure it is sent to the server.

Is this the right approach? If yes, what're the specifics? If not, what is?

Comment: I have the same question, wondering how to get a handle on the request-id in app insights.